# android make LinearLayout and its children transparent

Tags: android, android-layout, transparency, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a LinearLayout called `mySlab` inside another RelativeLayout. I need to make the `mySlab` and its children views transparent programmatically. Do I have to make each child transparent explicitly or is there a way such that if I turn `mySlab` transparent the children will follow?

**A bit of clarification**

The layout view in question has a number of children each with its own color or image background. I am hoping to be able to dial the transparency of `mySlab` without actually changing the colors and backgrounds of each child per se. iOS does that very well.

Also `mySlab` is actually a RelativeLayout, not Linear, though I don't think that should matter.

Comment: try this on the linear layout: android:background="@android:color/transparent

Comment: [`android:alpha`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:alpha) / [`setAlpha(float)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)) is what you want (See OP's comment on Saif's answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.myLayout);
for (int x=0;x<ll.getChildCount();x++)
    ll.getChildAt(x).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

this will change the LinearLayout and its childrens

Comment: + 1 for the suggestion. But that does not work well; it is basically a poor version of `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`. What I want is to apply a degree of transparency to the view, not to make them completely invisible. Also my linear layout contains children with both different color and image backgrounds. I was hoping to be able to dial the transparency without actually changing the colors and backgrounds per se. iOS does that very well.

Comment: I was able to do it using setAlpha

Answer (score 2):

its easy in android, use this property

```
android:background="#00FFFFFF";
```

where 00 is for tansparency, and rest for rgb color.

Comment: The children are not obeying the command. I do `.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"))` as well and it still fails.

Comment: no. just on the parent; and hoping it will cascade to the children.